# SUM data only when COUNT(*) > 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT pr.[name], SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,0)) count_yes,
  SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,1)) count_no,
   COUNT(p.id) AS tot
FROM   (aco.practices pr
      left JOIN aco.patients_practices ppr ON (ppr.practiceid = pr.id)
      left JOIN aco.patients p ON (p.id = ppr.patientid)
      LEFT JOIN aco.qmheader qm ON (qm.patientid = p.id AND qm.practiceid = pr.id)
)
WHERE  (pr.parentaco = 30982)
GROUP BY pr.[name]
ORDER BY pr.[name]
```

Here are some results

```
name    count_yes   count_no    tot
name1   0            1          0
name2   0            1          0
name3   0            273        273
name4   0            114        114
```

For the most part it is correct, the only thing I need is to not SUM on the count_no if the tot is 0.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: Do you want to have the row still appear with '0's, appear with NULLs, or no row at all?

Comment: want it to appear with 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `select` clause to:

```
SELECT pr.[name], 
       SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,0)) AS count_yes,
       (case when COUNT(p.id) > 0 then 
             SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,1))
        else
             0 end) AS count_no,
       COUNT(p.id) AS tot
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT pr.[name], SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,0)) count_yes,
  SUM(COALESCE(qm.iscompleted,1)) count_no,
   COUNT(p.id) AS tot
FROM   (aco.practices pr
      left JOIN aco.patients_practices ppr ON (ppr.practiceid = pr.id)
      left JOIN aco.patients p ON (p.id = ppr.patientid)
      LEFT JOIN aco.qmheader qm ON (qm.patientid = p.id AND qm.practiceid = pr.id)
)
WHERE  (pr.parentaco = 30982)
GROUP BY pr.[name]
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0
ORDER BY pr.[name]
```

Comment: This will only bring back the ones with 0 count, i need them whether they have patients or not.